# Override Mockito toString test output

Tags: java, junit, mockito, hamcrest

I have written a custom [Hamcrest `Matcher<Double>`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matcher.html) to use with [`Mockito.doubleThat`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Matchers.html#doubleThat%28org.hamcrest.Matcher%29).

I want to "override the `toString()`" method, so to speak, so that if there's a failure, the error is more verbose. Here's the JUnit failure trace:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
dependedOnComponent.method(
    <Double matcher>
);
-> at my.domain.TestClass.testMethod(TestClass.java:123)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
dependedOnComponent.method(
    123.45,
);
-> at my.domain.SystemUnderTest.callingMethod(SystemUnderTest.java:456)
```

As you can see, it prints `<Double matcher>`. Is it possible to override that message? Instead, I would like to see, as an example:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
dependedOnComponent.method(
    120 < matcher < 121
);
```

But a different instantiantion of my matcher class might be:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
dependedOnComponent.method(
    1 < matcher < 200
);
```

**I don't need to know how to write the code to generate the numbers or the syntax, I just need to know WHERE to put it.**

Comment: Regarding your comment on my now-deleted post - can you expand your question to give an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Updated answer should address this. Essentially the same solution, albeit better described :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was doing something silly; I was reading the Javadoc for [Matcher](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matcher.html) when I really should have been looking at the Javadoc for [ArgumentMatcher](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html).

Once I realized my mistake, it's easy; just override the `describeTo` method defined in that interface, e.g.

```
@Override
public void describeTo(Description description) {
    description.appendText(String.valueOf(expected));
    description.appendText(" ± ");
    description.appendText(String.valueOf(delta));
}
```

Comment: IIRC, the expectation is that you'll extend `CustomMatcher` (as per my answer) rather than `ArgumentMatcher`. It would be impossible to make this "mistake" when extending that class, because the constructor forces you to define the description.

Comment: Having written the above comment, I see that the Javadocs for `ArgumentMatcher` somewhat disagree with me. Oh well :-)

Comment: @Duncan Yah it's a Mockito thing, not a JUnit thing ;)

Comment: It seems strange that they've created a class that is essentially the same as Hamcrest's `CustomMatcher` class. I wonder why they've done that - perhaps just to avoid people declaring a dependency upon Hamcrest.

Comment: @Duncan [Mockito depends upon Hamcrest...](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.mockito%7Cmockito-core%7C1.9.5%7Cjar) Note that's mockito-core not mockito-all (translation: I don't know either)

Comment: Ah, mystery solved. The latest Mockito is built against Hamcrest 1.1, which doesn't contain the `CustomMatcher` class. So you would have to explicitly declare a dependency on a newer Hamcrest library for my solution to work. +1 to your solution for being the "Mockito way" :-)

Comment: @Duncan This is a good time for me to [post a link to this question I posted last year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770943/mockito-junit-hamcrest-versioning?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SOTest {

    public interface Foo {
        void doSomething(double d);
    }

    @Test
    public void sillyTest() {

        Foo foo = mock(Foo.class);
        foo.doSomething(1);
        verify(foo).doSomething(Mockito.doubleThat(new TestMatcher(2)));
    }

    public class TestMatcher extends CustomMatcher<Double> {

        private final double expected;

        public TestMatcher(double expected) {
            super(Double.toString(expected));
            this.expected = expected;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matches(Object item) {
            return item instanceof Double && ((Double) item).equals(expected);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
foo.doSomething(2.0);
-> at SOTest.sillyTest(SOTest.java:23)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
foo.doSomething(1.0);
-> at SOTest.sillyTest(SOTest.java:22)
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have made clear that I wanted the message to change based on the different instantiations

Comment: Thanks for your help, I ended up doing what I described in my answer. However, you definitely put me on the right track (because I realized that I wasn't implementing `Matcher`, I was extending `ArgumentMatcher`), so I gave you an upvote :)